# Comparison using load() in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, colors, load

I have 2 pages: data.php and index.html, data.php has only one value ( for example 99). Index.html is using jquery to load data.php every 2 second to a div "data"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#data').fadeIn("slow").load('data.php').fadeOut("slow")
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Now i want to change background color of div "data" when value in data.php is greater than 400 for example, but dont know how to do it, pls help ?

this is my code in data.php

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT data FROM DATA ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 1");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['data'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: You just need to use the callback of `load()` to do what you require. Is data.php returning HTML or text? We'd need to see the actual response to know where to look for the value to check. However, I'd strongly suggest you use websockets instead of AJAX polling. Right now you'd be DDOSing your own server if you have any decent number of concurrent users.

Comment: i used load(data.php) but it's not work.  I just want get the content of data.php as a variable so that i can comparison

Comment: for detail, data.php is a blank page has only "99"

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this? Inside your `data.php` something like this should work

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT data FROM DATA ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 1");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div id="mydata">'. $row['data'] .'</div><br>';
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#data').fadeIn("slow").load('data.php').fadeOut("slow");

    var mydata = $('#mydata');

    if (mydata.val() > 400) {
      mydata.css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
      mydata.css("background-color", "green");
    }

  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">
  <div id="mydata">
    99
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank for your help but this's not work, nothing happened

Comment: @Thịnh could you show me the html you have? the page have the data?

Comment: i select a newest record from my database to show on the data.php, and it looks like this http://imgur.com/a/aAoj3

Comment: could you wrap the 99 with a tag like `<div id="mydata">99</div>` ?

Comment: thank you but how to fix it because in my data.php is just <php>.. </php> and i just echo from database

Comment: @Thịnh where do you generate php? must be `echo` from somewhere right?

Comment: @Thịnh something like `echo '<div id="mydata">'. *your data here* .'</div>';`

Comment: oh sorry i will add my code in data.php in first post